# Get Public Key from Temple Wallet (Tezos)

Tags: blockchain

Is it possible to get the public key (not the public key hash) from an account of the Temple Wallet for the Tezos blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the public key directly from Temple wallet.
However you can get the public key from the private one that can be retrieved from Temple (setting/reveal secret key).

Then use tezos-client in your terminal :

```
$ tezos-client import secret key <account_alias> unencrypted:<your_secret_key>
$ tezos-client show address <account_alias>
```

where <account_alias> is a custom name you give to the imported account.

It return the pub key and it's hash.